# Count of properties in a collection of objects

Tags: c#, list, collections, count

I'm struggling how to get my head round this issue.

I have a class which stores cell information for each cell in a spreadsheet.

```
public class Datacollection 
{
    public int rowNumber { get; set; }
    public string colName { get; set; }
    public string colValue { get; set; }
}
```

Elsewhere I then load an excel spreadsheet as a collection of these objects

```
private static List<Datacollection> _dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();
```

The spreadsheet I'm loading has 3 columns and 3000 rows, so the size of my collection is 9000. One Datacollection object for each cell in the spreadsheet.

How might I get a row number count from this collection? I guess I would need the highest value of 'rowNumber' but I'm not sure how to get this value back.

Many thanks,

Comment: `_dataCol.Count()` would give a count of items. `_dataCol.Max(x=>x.rowNumer)` would give the max row number

Comment: Aside from the answer you've now received, now would be a good time to learn about .NET naming conventions and start following them. (I'd also suggest that something storing cell information would be better named `Cell` or `CellInformation` or similar, instead of `Datacollection`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row numbers are consecutive and start from 1, you can simply use LINQ's `Max` extension:

```
var rowCount = _dataCol.Max(cell => cell.rowNumber);
```

But if they do start at an arbitrary number instead of 1, or if there are gaps in the row numbers, you'd need to find the count of **distinct** row numbers:

```
var rowCount = _dataCol.Select(cell => cell.rowNumber).Distinct().Count();
```

---

If you are sure that every row has *exactly* three columns, a faster way would of course be `var rowCount = _dataCol.Count / 3;`

Comment: Wouldn't rowCount just be _dataCol.Count? 
Why do we need to divide by 3?

Comment: @AdityaKorti because `_dataCol` contains one element _per cell_. So `_dataCol.Count` is not only the number of rows, but the number of rows multiplied by the number of columns.

Comment: I thought it was for row.
one object per cell actually doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

To get the max value of `rowNumber` you can use LinQ:

```
var rowCount = _dataCol.Max(x => x.rowNumber);
```